# Discord.js ';' expected. x2

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have 2 problems with this code expected ';' 2 places, in front of run and behind { at the end of first line. When I start it I get this error.

```
async run(Client, oldMember, newMember) {
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

```
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', message => {

    async run(Client, oldMember, newMember) {
        const channel = Client.channel.cache.get('707524910658093058');

        if (oldMember.roles.cache.size !== newMember.roles.cache.size) {
            if (!oldMember.roles.cache.has('712325241845710878') && newMember.roles.cache.has
                ('712325241845710878')) {
                channel.send(`Thank ${newMember} for boosting you are awesome`);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to *do* here? Define a *function* named `run`?

Comment: well, I'm not sure rn, im new to this... and i watched a YT video, he did it so....

Comment: It's going to be hard to suggest what the code should be without knowing what's supposed to happen. A minimal syntax fix would be `async function run`, but then you're defining a function that never gets called.

Comment: it is supposed to send a message when people are boosting the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the way how `discord.js` [Client](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) events handling works.

Please look at [guildMemberUpdate event documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberUpdate), this is how you should do it :

```js
bot.on('guildMemberUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
        const channel = newMember.guild.channels.cache.get('707524910658093058');

        if (oldMember.roles.cache.size !== newMember.roles.cache.size) {
            if (!oldMember.roles.cache.has('712325241845710878') && newMember.roles.cache.has('712325241845710878')) {
                channel.send(`Thank ${newMember} for boosting you are awesome`);
            }
        }
});
```

I suggest you to take a look at [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/) to get started.

Comment: i got an TypeError: cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

from: const channel = bot.channel.cache.get('707524910658093058');

Comment: and what do you mean by mark my questions as accepted the answer that I feel fits best with my question

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in my code sample, I edited it, now it should be fine. About marking accepted answer I suggest you to see [stackoverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)